# how to sort an NSMutable Array reference to date in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

Hello All I need to sort an NSMutable Array that having a class Objects say Item .
Item class have date,url,link,title,guid etc .. I am storing this Object Into an NsMutableArray each time.
so MyArray will have number Of Item class Objects ..
 now I need to sort Myarray using date attribute .
Can any one tell me the way.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor withKey:@"date" ascending:YES]; // or NO, if you want descending

[yourMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Comment: Thanks alot for a very quick response.. I did the same kind of work like
  
 [array sortUsingDescriptor:descriptor];
  but its giving an exception ...

Answer (score 2):

If MyArray only holds `NSDate*` Objects then:

```
NSArray* mySortedArray = [MyArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]
```

This will call the following method on your `NSDate` objects.

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)aNumber
```